# Java SWT/Jface TreeColumn freeze

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

I have create a TreeViewer with data, but the TreeColumn is so much , so I want to ask a question how can freeze the first TreeColumn, thanks

Comment: TreeViewer doesn't support that. Maybe look at [NatTable](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.